# Stacked Lines in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to draw stacked lines in `pandas Dataframe`.
So, currently I draw one line:

```
df.plot.line(x='xvals',y='yvals')
```

in which `xvals` column contains `x` values, and `yvals` contains `y` values.

How can I add another line in the same graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the returned `Axes` object and pass to `ax` argument:

```
ax = df.plot.line(x='xvals',y='yvals')
df.plot.line(x='xvals2',y='yvals2', ax=ax)
```